# Is there a good way to access information outside of a function?

Tags: c++, recursion, optimization

Currently, I am working in C++ on a recursive function that to work, needs to be passed a large array and several constant variables. Here is the structure of the recursion:

```
void recurse_objects(std::vector<Object> &objects, int i, int j, double merge_distance, double size_enclosure, double timestep){

    //operations performed

    //recursion performed
    if(j+1 < objects.size()){
        recurse_objects(objects, i, j+1, merge_distance, size_enclosure, timestep);
    }else if(i+2 < objects.size()){
        recurse_objects(objects, i+1, i+2, merge_distance, size_enclosure, timestep);
    }

    //more operations performed
}
```

The function recurses through each unique pair (i, j) of objects. The problem is, at the amount of objects I am working at (500-2000 objects), the function segmentation faults due to the stack filling up - it works for under 350 objects.

It feels like if I could store the array and constant variables somewhere else, I could save room and be able to run computation on those last few objects. Is there a common fix to this problem? The only ones I could think of are using global variables - not feasible since values are dictated by system input, to batch, which would completely kill the efficiency, or just to change the program to a non-recursive one.

Comment: The objects in the vector reference are already stored elsewhere. Doubly so. First because the vector uses dynamic memory, and second because there's a single vector whose reference is passed recursively.

Comment: And the real solution is to use an iterative solution instead of a recursive one

Comment: My experience shows that recursive functions shall have a call depth proportional to **O(log n)** maximum. Like divide-and-conquer or tree traversal algorithms. If the depth in **O(n)**, a stack overflow could easily happen, but the algorithm can normally be converted into a loop.

Comment: Sounds like I will have to use iterative - the goal for this project is cache optimization, which is the only reason I wanted to try out recursive (other than looking cleaner). Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler is not performing tail-call optimization, recursive functions that run too long will always cause a stack overflow. Cutting down the amount of memory stored in each stack frame will delay that inevitable, and let you run it on larger datasets, but they won't remove the problem, since even *small* stack frames add up.

Your function already appears to be on its way to being tail-recursive, *if* there are no more operations after the recursive calls.

If you can get rid of those *after* your recursive call, this will likely come down to what flags you're sending your compiler for optimization.

Comment: @Richard Really? I thought the point of tail recursion optimizations were that if your sole point of recursion is a `return nextRecusriveCall(...);` then you could reuse the current stack frame for `nextRecursiveCall`. I don't see how that could be the case if the current call has more operations to do after `nextRecursiveCall` returns.

Comment: @Nathan My bad. I interpreted those calls as functionally equivalent to return given the void, but you're right and they need not be.

Comment: Both computations are necessary: the first calculates all accelerations, then the operations after calculate the velocities. I'd have to split the recursion up. Going to go with iterative probably.